# Best way to make a web interface for python script

Tags: python, web, interface

I've made a small python script to scrap the web. I would like to make a nice and simple web interface where the user can enter data to search for and have the result displayed as a list. 
I understand that there's many different ways to do that but don't know which one would be the best in my case.

I would like something :

- Really simple and light
- Running locally with the less dependencies possible.

So far I've thinking about :

- A NodeJS server displaying content and executing the script
- A web framework in Python (web.py, Flask, Django..?)
- A local webserver (XAMPP) and cgi

Please note that I don't know much about web in python but I'm a bit used to NodeJS.

What would you recommend ?

Thanks, Victor

Comment: This is a highly opinionated question, but I will answer in a comment. If you are already comfortable with NodeJS, I would recommend going forward with NodeJS along with something like the Express framework. This should get you up and running rather quickly and easily.

Comment: Flask is certainly a good choice for your two requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I prefer gevent, bottle or Flask, and some front end framework like bootstrap or framework7.

Gevent easily makes it asynchronous and has websockets built right in, and bottle is the easiest (and fastest) way to build a web app or api.

Comment: I took a look at bottle and it seems exactly what I need, thanks.

Comment: If you need any assistance, I have a ton of code I can give you that would get you a jumpstart.  Just add gmail to my screen name.

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io ist Very easy to send Data between Websites and scripts.
The Website Connect with the Socket.io Server and Inside the Server the Python Script can be executed